# How to NOT show the current user in a Grid View?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have a function called `getAllUsers()` that returns all users from a database. The problem is that I want `GridView.builder()` to display all the users except the current user, but despite all the research I did, nothing seems to work out.

If i use the if condition like `if(snapshot.data.documents[i].data["username"] != currentUserId` within `itemBuilder:`, it returns a blank tile which represents the current user which creates a gap within the grid view. Thus, it makes the grid view look really bad.

I believe this problem could have been solved if I knew how to include the inequality query in the `getAllUsers()` method. But my understanding is that Firestore has yet to provide this function/argument.

**HomeFragment class**

```
  Database _database = Database();
  Stream _stream;
  String currentUserId;

  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentUserId();
    getAllUsers();
    super.initState();
  }

  getAllUsers() async {
    return await _database.getAllUsers().then((val) {
      if (mounted)
        setState(() => _stream = val);
    });
  }

  getCurrentUserId() async {
    FirebaseUser currentUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    currentUserId = currentUser.uid;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _stream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.data == null ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
          child:
              GridView.builder(
                gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                ),
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    return Container(
                       child: Text(snapshot.data.documents[i].data["username"])
                    );
                }
                // etc etc..
```

**Database class**

```
getAllUsers() async {
    return await _firestore.collection("users").snapshots();
}
```

I tried to use this, but `_stream2` returns null

```
Stream _stream, _stream2;

    getAllUsers() async {
    return await _database.getAllUsers().then((val) {
      if (mounted) {
        List<String> list;
        setState(() {
          _stream = val;
          _stream2 = _stream.where((snapshot) {
            _querySnapshot = snapshot;
            for (int i = 0; i < _querySnapshot.documents.length; i++)
              list.add(_querySnapshot.documents[i].data["userId"]);
            return list.contains(currentUserId) == false;
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

I also tried this, it is not working

```
getAllUsers() async {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = await _database.getAllUsers();
    _stream = snapshots.map((snapshot) {
      snapshot.documents.where((documentSnapshot) {
        return documentSnapshot.data["userId"] != currentUserId;
      });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try something like this. You filter the query result:

```
 getAllUsers() async {
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = await _firestore.collection("users").snapshots();
    return snapshots.map((snapshot) {
       final result = snapshot.documents
             .map((snapshot) => User.fromMap(snapshot.data)
             .where((user) => user.id != currentUser.id)
             .toList();
             
       return result;
   }
}
```

If you do not have an User class, you can replace some lines with this. But the result will be a list of Map<String, dynamic> instead of a list of User objects.

```
return snapshots.map((snapshot) {
           final result = snapshot.documents
                 .map((snapshot) => snapshot.data
                 .where((user) => user['id'] != currentUser.id)
                 .toList();
                 
           return result;
```

Comment: what does the User.fromMap() do? changes map to user type?

Comment: It's a factory constructor that converts the data from the snapshot to a User object. You don't have a User class?

Comment: i dont have a user model

Comment: I'll edit the method to get the raw data, but as a good practice you should create a User class.

Comment: Yes. You got some error? Can you show how do you added the method?

Comment: I just included the method in the question. plesase check. in the method i just posted `_stream2` returns null, even if i do it your way, it still returns null.

Comment: Your methods has some errors. But, then instead of filter the query result, just remove the element from the list that you get from your original method. Like this: `snapshot.data.documents.removeWhere((user) => user['userId'] != currentUser.id);`

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked well for me.

```
firestore.collection('your collection').where('x', isNotEqualTo: auth.currentUser!.uid).snapshots();
```